# Using projections in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system

I have digitised glaciers in Southern Chile and at one stage, my shapefiles were lining up perfectly and somewhere along the way I have obviously changed something and now the shapefiles do not line up with the image. I have tried changing the projections and even when they are set to the same projected coordinate system and they end up nowhere near each other. I can set the image to WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_19N and the shapefile to WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_24N, the polygons are on the image but they are just slightly off to the right of where they should be.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour] ro better understand what is expected in a question.  Please [edit] the question to specify the *exact* sequence of commands you have used.  It's very likely you have mangled the coordinate system associated with the data though improper use of CS definition and reprojection. If you don't remember the exact sequence you may need to start over again, keeping track you what you are changing.

Comment: Please also edit the question with the extents of both the image and the shapefile.